# Program is showing SEGMENTATION error on SPOJ ,inspite of running fine on PC?

Tags: c

http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/
This program is showing SEGMENTATION error when I run it on SPOJ ,but it runs fine on my PC(i.e codeblocks),,where is the flaw?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t,m,n,fl=0;
    int i,j,q,w;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int arr[t];
    for(i=0;i<2*t;++i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<t*2;i+=2)
    {

        n=arr[i];m=arr[i+1];
        if(n==1)++n;
        for(j=n;j<=m;++j)
        {
            q=j;
            for(w=2;w<q;++w)
            {
                if(q%w==0){fl=1;break;}
            }
            if(fl==0){printf("%d",q);printf("\n");}
            fl=0;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

You create an array of size `t` but then use it with indexes up to `2*t`. You likely should create it with size `2*t` to begin with.

```
int arr[2*t];
```

You can usually catch these types of errors by running your program under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) or a similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong:

```
int arr[t];
for(i=0;i<2*t;++i)
{
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
```

You create an array of size `t`, and then put `2*t` elements into it.  Kaboom.  Your code may have other bugs, too - that one just jumped out at me.